# What accounts for increase in time to execute -type f in find

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find

I have done the following commands, on a combination of Volumes which contains about 1M files.

```
$ sudo find "$FULFILLMENT" "$ARCH1" "$ARCH2" "$MASTERING"
Tue Jan 29 15:04:05 PST 2013
Tue Jan 29 15:22:46 PST 2013
18m41s


$ sudo find "$FULFILLMENT" "$ARCH1" "$ARCH2" "$MASTERING" -type f
Tue Jan 29 15:24:06 PST 2013
Tue Jan 29 15:49:10 PST 2013
25m4s
```

Why does using `-type f` take so much longer than the normal find command? I would think it would be quicker, since it didn't have to iterate through all the files (perhaps 20% less files). What accounts for the increase in time?

Comment: To benchmark, you need to run the command many times to account for your computer doing other tasks. I'd also use the "time" command to measure the amount of time the command takes. To answer your question, you can probably look at the source of "find".

Comment: What do `$FULFILLMENT`, `$ARCH1`, `$ARCH2`, and `$MASTERING` expand to? Are they directory names?

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, they are Volume names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the `-type f` parameter, `find` will not `stat` each file, but use the `readdir` system call to get directory entries, reducing the number of system calls, context switches, inode lookups etc.

It's possible for `find` to use a query optimizer in this specific case.  Look up the `-O2` option in the man page for `find`.  Your query would become:

```
$ sudo find -O2 "$FULFILLMENT" "$ARCH1" "$ARCH2" "$MASTERING" -type f
```

This should have the same performance of the find without the `-type f` since it will try to use the file type information returned by the `readdir` system call if available rather than requiring a separate `stat` call for every file.

**Further background:**

Not all file systems support returning the file `type` information in the `readdir` call, and not all versions of `find` will be compiled with support for this extended type information.

If `find --version` reports the `D_TYPE` feature, then your find supports reading this additional type information.  File system types ext2, ext3, ext4 support the `D_TYPE` field.

Answer (score 1):

It would have to iterate through the directory and do a `stat` on them to find out if they are files (not directories, symbolic links etc).

PS: I am making some assumptions over the values "$FULFILLMENT" "$ARCH1" "$ARCH2" "$MASTERING"

Comment: But it has to do that anyway to find subdirectories to recurse into.